# Connecting comboboxes created in a loop in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a GUI that is generated dynamically based on some input dictionary. I'm using the GridLayout, iterate over the dictionary keys and generate per iteration/grid row the key of the dictionary as a QLineEdit (to give some background color as a visual cue) and two comboboxes next to it. Ideally, the second combobox would change its items based on what is selected in the first combobox. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.Widgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QComboBox

class GUI(QMainWindow):
    """App View"""
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.generalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._displayview()

    def _displayview(self):
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        subdict = self.data
        combolist = ['Auto', 'Select value', 'Calculate']

        maxwidth = sum([len(key) for key in subdict.keys()])
        self.count = 0

        for item in subdict.keys():
            color = subdict[item]['Color']

            # Display tags and bg-color
            display = QLineEdit()
            display.setMaximumWidth(maxwidth-maxwidth//4)
            display.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit"
            "{"
            f"background : {color}"
            "}")
            display.setText(item)
            display.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            display.setReadOnly(True)

            # Combobox action
            self.cb_action = QComboBox()
            if color == 'Lightgreen':
                self.cb_action.addItem('Auto')
                self.cb_action.setEnabled(False)
            else:
                self.cb_action.addItems(combolist)

            # Combobox value
            self.cb_value = QComboBox()
            self.cb_value.addItem('Text')

            self.cb_action.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.react)

            self.layout.addWidget(display, self.count, 0)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.cb_action, self.count, 1)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.cb_value, self.count, 2)

            self.count += 1
        self.generalLayout.addLayout(self.layout)

    def react(self):
        ... # my humble approaches here
```

Basically, the first combobox has the three options: Auto, Select value and Calculate and based on that selection, the combobox next to it should present different options (right now, it only has 'Text' for testing purposes).

I tried different approaches in the `self.react()`, e.g. a simple `self.cb_value.addItem('something')`, which would however add the item in the last combobox (which makes sense). I also tried to simply build a new combobox with `self.layout.addWidget()`, however without an index, that won't work. Lastly, I tried to simply create that second column of comboboxes anew in another iteration using `self.cb_action.currentText()` as help, however, that again returns only the text from the last combobox.

I understand that due to the nature of creating everything while iterating I get these problems. It's not unlikely that I haven't fully understood the concept of widgets. Would anybody be so kind to point me in the right direction how I would do this with variable input data? I'd probably face the same issue when I tried to extract all these information from the comboboxes to get some output I can work with.

Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: The main problem is the continuous overwriting of instance attributes, so `self.something` will always be the last object set for it. There are various possible approaches, and it all depends on what you will need to do *after*, not only the part that updates the second combobox, but also their future access and interaction, and without knowing that we can't give a definitive solution (nor *any possible* one). Consider that you may create a QWidget subclass as a container (with its own horizontal layout), which will make connections easier, and add those to the main layout instead.

Comment: Eventually, I would like to collect the selections made in these comboboxes. Another idea would be to extent the current layout with more widgets to allow further customizations. In the end, the selections would be needed outside the GUI. Do you mind sharing a little more detail on the QWidget subclass you mentioned? I don‘t know how to keep this whole thing dynamic.